# Why this code doesn't work?

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

i get a segmentation here.
However if i declare array as int** and use malloc, it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int **p,int numRows,int numCols) //Second Method//
{
    printf("\n");
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i< numRows;i++)
    {

        for (j = 0;j< numCols;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    int arr[2][2]={{1,2},{4,5}};
        display(arr,2,2);
}
```

PS I don't need an alternative way,
just tell me why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Did you see compiler warnings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `int**` is a pointer to a pointer, while an `int [2][2]` contiguously stores two arrays. That's your mistake.

With `int x[2][2]`, when you do `x[1]`, you tell the compiler to access memory by skipping one set of two elements, and the resulting expression is an array of two elements. With `int** x`, when you do `x[1]`, you tell the compiler to access memory by skipping *one pointer*. While you access data the same way for both, the two are simply not laid out the same way.

In memory, `x[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}` looks like this:

```
// 4 contiguous elements
01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00    04 00 00 00  05 00 00 00
```

While `int** x` looks like this:

```
// pointers to integers
aa bb cc dd  aa ab ac ad
// At [aa bb cc dd]:
    01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00
// At [aa ab ac ad]:
    04 00 00 00  05 00 00 00
```

Therefore, to adapt for an `int**`, you must create an array of `int*` pointers dynamically and set each entry to the lower dimension of your array.

Comment: I'll get back to you on this,...
it'll take a while to get all this.

Answer (score 6):

`arr` is an array of 2 arrays of 2 `int`s.  When it's used in an expression without being the subject of either the unary `&` or `sizeof` operators, it evaluates to a pointer to its first element.

This is a "pointer to an array of 2 `int`", which is the type `int (*)[2]`.  It is *not* a pointer to a pointer to `int`, which is the type `int **`.  Furthermore, these types are not compatible, and you can't pass the former to a function expecting the latter.

An `int **` must be pointing at something that itself is a pointer.  The pointer you are passing to `display` is pointing at an array, not a pointer.

Comment: @user2714365: No, it does not.  `arr` *is* an array of arrays - there are no pointers, it is just a block of 4 `int`s.  When you pass it to a function, it evaluates to a pointer, but that pointer points at an array (the first of the two sub-arrays in `arr`).

Answer (score 4):

Please don't neglect warnings

`expected int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[2]`

`arr` is an array of 2 arrays of 2 integers

Use :

`void display(int p[][2],int numRows,int numCols)`